# beacon based notification on Andriod without Nearby API

Tags: beacon

Google has discontinued Near By API by the end of 2018. Android OS had built in support for Near by API and hence without a custom APP , the device was able to capture the beacon based push notifications.My requirement is as follows:
With Digital loyalty pass on Google wallet, when the end customer enters the vicinity  of a beacon , the device should receive offers as push notification.  There is no custom app developed . With out a custom app , how to receive the push notifications with just the Digital loyalty pass on google wallet? . Please help with a solution.

Please refer https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/discontinuing-support-for-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately after Google Nearby was discontinued, **there is no longer a solution to send notifications to  a user on BLE detection without a third party app** installed to do so.

The only workaround is to develop a third party app to do the detecting and notifying. Keep in mind that the way Google implemented this was with the Google Play Services app, so an app was still required to send the notifications.  (It was just an app that was installed by default on most phones sold outside of mainland China.). And it didn't even work unless a user had opted in, something that few ever did.

Google's Nearby discontinuation basically says Google is no longer willing to use their app to send notifications for you.  So you must use your own app or the app of a different partner.

There are other third party apps that track a user's location and send notifications -- such apps are often popular "free" games.  But while the install base of these apps can be in the hundreds of millions they do not approach the install base of Google Play Services.  These apps can also be a bit "shady" about their practices, and to my knowledge do not have a public policy about how you can get them to send notifications for you or let users opt-in or opt-out.